# "The format of the URI could not be determined" when combining absolute and relative URLs in C#

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, ftp, uri

I have a script that accesses an FTP server, and gets a list of files under a directory:

```
//line 65 of Status script that is mentioned in error message
string[] list = ftp.DirectoryListSimple("AdvancedCalender/Calenders/Versions");
```

```
//ftp.DirectoryListSimple()
//FTP script that is mentioned in error message
public string[] DirectoryListSimple(string directory)
{
    try
    {
        Uri serverUri = new Uri(host);
        Uri relativeUri = new Uri("/" + directory);
        Uri fullUri = new Uri(serverUri, relativeUri);
        ftpRequest = (FtpWebRequest)FtpWebRequest.Create(fullUri);

        ftpRequest.Credentials = new NetworkCredential(user, pass);

        ftpRequest.UseBinary = true;
        ftpRequest.UsePassive = true;
        ftpRequest.KeepAlive = true;

        ftpRequest.Method = WebRequestMethods.Ftp.ListDirectory;

        ftpResponse = (FtpWebResponse)ftpRequest.GetResponse();

        ftpStream = ftpResponse.GetResponseStream();

        StreamReader ftpReader = new StreamReader(ftpStream);

        string directoryRaw = null;

        try { while (ftpReader.Peek() != -1) { directoryRaw += ftpReader.ReadLine() + "|"; } }
        catch (Exception ex) { Debug.LogError(ex.ToString()); }

        ftpReader.Close();
        ftpStream.Close();
        ftpResponse.Close();
        ftpRequest = null;

        try { string[] directoryList = directoryRaw.Split("|".ToCharArray()); return directoryList; }
        catch (Exception ex) { Debug.LogError(ex.ToString()); }
    }
    catch (Exception ex) { Debug.LogError(ex.ToString()); }
    //^ error caught here
    return new string[] { "" };
}
```

Error message:

> System.UriFormatException: Invalid URI: The format of the URI could not be determined.
> at System.Uri.CreateThis (System.String uri, System.Boolean dontEscape, System.UriKind uriKind) [0x0007b] in :0
> at System.Uri..ctor (System.String uriString) [0x00014] in :0
> at BtStudios.HelperClasses.FtpHelpers.FTP.DirectoryListSimple (System.String directory) [0x0000b] in C:\Users\btowr\OneDrive\Desktop\Advanced Calender\Assets\FTP.cs:299
> UnityEngine.Debug:LogError (object)
> BtStudios.HelperClasses.FtpHelpers.FTP:DirectoryListSimple (string) (at Assets/FTP.cs:330)
> Status:Start () (at Assets/Status.cs:65)

I can confirm that I can connect to the FTP server, I can confirm that the files exist, and I can confirm that the URI format is correct (at least that I know of).

(EDIT) If you need to see a variable that is used in the function, I can share it, but sensitive information, such as the ip, username and password will not be the same as the real ip username and password.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `"/AdvancedCalender/Calenders/Versions"` is a *relative* URI, so you need to tag is like that:

```
Uri relativeUri = new Uri("/" + directory, UriKind.Relative);
```